# IE7 drop-down menu over flash - borders send mouseover to flash

Tags: css, flash, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

edit: **tl;dr: 
in ie7, a css dropmenu element borders yield mouse focus to a flash object underneath the drop down bit. help.**

hi.
i'm trying to create a css dropdown menu that appears over a flash object. this menu is created using a ul > li > a hierarchy, and the "a" tags have a border. the problem i'm having is that in IE7, when the mouse passes over the border of the "a" tags, a mouseover event is sent to the flash object underneath, and a mouseout is sent to the menu. this causes the menu to disappear when the mouse is moved down the menu.

i found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367110/drop-down-menu-disappears-and-comes-back-only-in-ie7-problem) but am not sure how to implement the solution for a vertical menu.

relevant code samples (i realize that much of this is a complete mess, but i was given most of this from the designer and can't spend time rewriting it to be slightly less... ugh :P)

**css:**

```
 d.menu-td:hover ul.submenu, td.iehover ul.submenu, ul.submenu li:hover, ul.submenu li a:hover,
td.hmenu-td:hover ul.submenu, td.iehover ul.submenu li, td.iehover ul.submenu li a{
 display:block;
} 
ul.submenu li{
 border-top: 2px solid #000;
 display: block;
}
ul.submenu li a:link, ul.submenu li a:visited{
 font-size: 12px;
 padding: 2px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #277aab;
 height: 34px;
 color: #93bdd5;
}
ul.submenu li a:hover, ul.submenu li a:active{
 background-color: #319edf;
 color: #1f628d;
}
```

**html:**

**the flash movie:**

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="990" height="280" id="header" align="middle" onmouseover="alert('111');">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="./upload/<?=$page_flash?>" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<embed src="./upload/<?=$page_flash?>" quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="990" height="280" name="header" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

**the dropdown menu:**

```
<td align="center" class="menu-td">
   <a href="index.php?p=2" class="menu">סניפים</a>
      <div style="position:relative;left:35px;">
         <ul class="submenu">
            <li>
               <a href="index.php?p=9" class="menu">link1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="index.php?p=10" class="menu">link2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="index.php?p=11" class="menu">link3</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="index.php?p=12" class="menu">link4</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="index.php?p=13" class="menu">link5</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="index.php?p=14" class="menu">link6</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
  </td>
```

**a bit of javascript to help make ie recognize the hover event:**

```
 <!--[if gte IE 5.5]>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("td.menu-td, td.hmenu-td").hover(
    function() { jQuery(this).addClass("iehover"); },
    function() { jQuery(this).removeClass("iehover"); }
     );
   });
  </script>
 <![endif]-->
```

a link to the actual page:
[link text](http://afik-p.co.il/hns/index.php?p=9)
(the offending menu is the second link for the right at the top of the page).

any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add any background color to submenu `<ul>`. Basically if item doesn't have background then it is also "transparent" for mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to to is make your flash transparent like [this (point 6)](http://www.anim-fx.com/flash-tutorials/flashtransparency.html).

Comment: already tried that. i changed to opaque cause i saw that suggestion elsewhere, which also didn't work.